# What does "[Ljava.lang.Object;@" mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am filling a Google spreadsheet from a form. The code writes some information into the spreadsheet, it always does it right, but before writing what it is supposed to, it writes `[Ljava.lang.Object;@1c7aa4fc` (or something like that) on the last row in the spreadsheet. Why is it appearing there?

The code for writing into the spreadsheet:

```
for (var p = 1; p < data.length; p++) {
    var ppopis = data[p][2]; 
    var sstav = data[p][7];
    var ukonceno_dne = data[p][9];
    var cell = spred2.getRange("H"+(p+1));
    var celll = spred2.getRange("J"+(p+1));
    if(nadpis_pole == ppopis && vlozena_hodnota == "Zrušeno") {
      cell.clear();
      cell.setValue("Zrušeno");
      if(ukonceno_dne == "" || ukonceno_dne == null){
        celll.setValue(dnesni_datum);
      }
    } else if (nadpis_pole == ppopis && vlozena_hodnota == "Vráceno") {
      cell.clear();
      cell.setValue("Vráceno");
      if(ukonceno_dne == "" || ukonceno_dne == null){
        celll.setValue(dnesni_datum);
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@....` is the start of a Java class; does `dnesdi_datum` obtain its contents from a Java program?

Comment: dnesni_datum means today´s date, which is generated earlier in the code

Comment: log all contents before the setValue so we see them

Comment: You should be able to write a JavaScript `Date` directly to the sheet - show how `dnesni_datum` is created.

Answer (score 8):

App script has underlying data structure built up on java...Ljava.lang..... represents object notation in Java to indicate any object such as Array,JSON in GAS.To get actual value try **toString()**  (or) **JSON.Stringify()** and check whether you have a value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it didnt help :/ i don´t know, probably the problem must be elsewere

Answer (score 6):

Be careful of when you do value setting. You could be passing an array ( or an object type ) by mistake, and you really want to insert a string.

For Example:

```
        ...
        aSheet.appendRow([["hello world"]]);
```

Will append "Java.Lang.Object" into the first cell of the appended row.

The correct API will be:

```
        ...
        aSheet.appendRow(["hello world"]); // single array
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. It's an easy mistake to make if you're usually writing data to Sheets using `Range.setValues(values)` because that does expect `[["hello world"]]`.

Comment: I am still getting the same result, using both the examples

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem on my side. I used 2D arrays for both appendRow and setValues methods in my code, which was wrong for appendRow because it appends only 1 row, therfore only a 1D array is required.

Comment: This was the issue for me