# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.ArrayMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, android

I encountered a weird bug while doing JUnit test.

I'm using reflection to call a method I defined:
MyReflectUtil.callMethod(testManager, "loadPermission");
Within the testManager there is an instance of ArrayMap. And loadPermission would call get() and put() on that instance.

This is the ArrayMap I defined:

```
public class ArrayMap<K, V> {
    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Within the method loadPermission, I can call get() method, but when I call put() , I get the error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.ArrayMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

What is this **Ljava/lang/Object**?
When I log myArrayMapInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethods(), I get:

public java.lang.Object android.util.ArrayMap.get(java.lang.Object), public void android.util.ArrayMap.put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)

It does not have the letter L in front of java.lang.Object. Yet I can not explain why I can call get(), because it is fundamentally the same as put().

Can anyone help? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Concerning your question, "What is this Ljava/lang/Object?", see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582248/what-does-ljava-lang-object-mean).

Comment: This class makes no sense to me at all, why would you name it `ArrayMap<K, V>`? You can't even define a constructor without getting compile errors on `>`? As far as I'm aware, class names can't have spaces?

Comment: @yur, this is the Generic in Java. You can check the definition of java.util.List in java as an example. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ljava/lang/Object;` after the closing bracket is the expected method's return type:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> android.util.ArrayMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)**Ljava/lang/Object;**

Your call expects a method that returns something, but in your `ArrayMap` code, this `put` method is `void`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added return value for put() now it works perfectly fine!